# CSS dialog with header and auto content

Tags: html, css, dialog, overflow

I'm working on HTML/CSS dialog window which has header and scrollable body.
I want to have body sizable to its content, but show scrollbars in body if the dialog higher than browser window. Unfourtantely I can't make body scrollable, how can I fix it?
Here is the code that I use (jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4Xvfm/1/):

```
<div class="dialog">
    <div class="header">Header</div>
    <div class="content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur, error, sunt, quaerat aliquid voluptatem dolorum in amet facere dolores cumque magnam placeat! Numquam, nisi, possimus facere iure eos minus repellat.
    </div>
</div>
```

And CSS styles:

```
.dialog {
    background-color: red;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 400px;
    max-height: 100%;

    /* Place dialog at the center of the screen */
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.dialog > .header,
.dialog > .footer {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 50px;
}

.dialog > .content {
    /* This doesn't work! */
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change overflow value to scroll like
"overflow:scroll"

Comment: you need to mention its max-height too.. try to mention max-height:300px content body . it ll work!

Comment: Thanks! But is there any way to not specify px values for content body? Content body could be pretty high and I want to limit it only with browser window.

Comment: Try to calculate heightaccording to windows height . if you got your answer tick accept to answer.

Comment: Looks like I will need JS code to update height on windows size change. It is possible, but it'd be good to find pure CSS solution.